# Не ходят пакеты между сетью за OpenVPN клиентом и сервером OpenVPN. Маршруты есть все

Tags: centos, openvpn, centos7, ping, передача-данных

Имеется сеть, состоящая из Cisco 2901, OpenVPN клиента на CentOS и OpenVPN сервера на CentOS:

[image: scheme]

На всех устройствах поднят BGP, маршруты имеются на всех.
Но проблема заключается в том, что с cisco ping идет до 192.168.99.2 (ovpn-cli), а вот уже до 192.168.99.1 (ovpn-srv) ping не идет.
Соответственно с ovpn-srv ping идет до 192.168.99.2, а вот уже до 10.0.17.243 пакеты не доходят:

[image: scheme-1]

P.S.
SELINUX отключен.
firewalld отключен.
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 есть.
P.P.S.
Я точно не могу сказать, но ведь может быть проблема в настройках OpenVPN? Если нужно, могу скинуть конфигурационные файлы и клиента, и сервера.
P.P.P.S.
Спасибо за ваше уделенное внимание!

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема решена.
В настройках конфигурации сервера и клиента OSPF нужно использовать dev tap, а не dev tun.